# check media resolution, if resolution is big ffmpeg it, if output is smaller than original delete the original else delete the output

Tags: linux, video, command-line, ffmpeg

I have my storage VPS filled with videos, and hoping I can free up some space, their resolution is pretty big so I decided to re encode them with ffmpeg to a smaller resolution, I am doing every thing manually, first I check using `mediainfo test5.mkv` the resolution

```
...
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
...
```

if the width is greater than `720 pixels` I issue the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i 'test5.mkv' -vf scale=720:-2 -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 -scodec copy -threads 12 -crf 28 -x264-params keyint=240:min-keyint=20 -preset:v slow '[Encoded] test5.mkv'
```

then after that I delete the original video if the output has smaller size than the original

I am hoping there is a script that can automate this, like I will run on a directory then, it will look for all `.mkv` to subdirectories recursively to perform this checks and actions. How to do this?

Also, I am worried that it could fail if I reach automation, since there are special characters in the video's name of some like single quotes, double quotes, or `, so I will it can be escaped properly.

Thanks!

After some google I ended up with the following snippet, I am worried if this is enough, but I'm afraid to run it since I am not sure if it would damage my unix

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in *.{mkv}; do
target="[720p]-${file%.*}.mkv"
[[ -f "$target" ]] && { echo "skipping $file - $target exists" ; continue; }


eval $(ffprobe -v error -of flat=s=_ -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height,width "$file")
size=${streams_stream_0_width}x${streams_stream_0_height}
if [ "$streams_stream_0_width" -ge 720 ]; then
echo ffmpeg -i "$file" -vf scale=720:-2 -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 -scodec copy -threads 12 -crf 28 -x264-params keyint=240:min-keyint=20 -preset:v slow "$target"

fi
done
```

can somebody please tell me if my snippet should work?

**UPDATE**

as it turns out `if [ "$streams_stream_0_width" -ge 720 ]; then` fails because the width is not integer? `line 10: [: : integer expression expected` I am not sure why it is not integer, how can I make it integer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that there is more code that sets the value for `${streams_stream_0_width}` and `${streams_stream_0_height}`. If not, your code will not know the value for those variables, and will fail.

But, you're missing 2 things, both can be solved with the shells arithmetic substitution syntax

```
size=$(( ${streams_stream_0_width} * ${streams_stream_0_height} ))
if (( "$streams_stream_0_width" > 720 )); then
    echo ffmpeg -i "$file" -vf scale=720:-2 -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 -scodec copy -threads 12 -crf 28 -x264-params keyint=240:min-keyint=20 -preset:v slow "$target"
fi
```

*Note that for multiplication, you use the standard `*` operator, and not the `x` character.*

Double `(( ... ))` parens give you arithmetic evaluations and you can use most `c` language features, like `x++`, `x+=12`, `x--` as well as comparison operators, like `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`.

And with a leading `$` , you have a command-substitution feature that does the same arithmetic evaluations, like `result=$(( ... ))`

As I don't have access to the files that you are using, I don't have an easy way to test your command for `ffmpeg`.

Finally, inside of `(( ... ))` and `$(( ... ))` you don't need to use `$` at the front of variable names, so you code can further be simplified as

```
size=$(( streams_stream_0_width * streams_stream_0_height ))
if (( streams_stream_0_width > 720 )); then
    echo ffmpeg -i "$file" -vf scale=720:-2 -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 -scodec copy -threads 12 -crf 28 -x264-params keyint=240:min-keyint=20 -preset:v slow "$target"
fi
```

IHTH